# Limit : $\lim_{n\to+\infty}a^n(n-\zeta(2)-\zeta(3)-\cdots-\zeta(n))$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, summation, closed-form

## question

1. Compute the limit $$\displaystyle{\lim_{n\to+\infty}a^n(n-\zeta(2)-\zeta(3)-\cdots-\zeta(n))}$$, if any, for the various values of the positive real a, where $\zeta$ the zeta function of Mr. Riemann.
2. Be areal with $|a|<2$. Prove that $$\displaystyle{\sum_{n\geq2}a^n(n-\zeta(2)-\zeta(3)-\cdots-\zeta(n))=a\left(\frac{\Psi(2- a)+\gamma}{1-a}-1\right)}$$, where $\Psi$ the function digamma.

### My work

$$\sum\limits_{k=2}^n \zeta(k) = \sum\limits_{k=2}^n \sum\limits_{m=1}^\infty \frac{1}{m^k} = \sum\limits_{m=1}^\infty \sum\limits_{k=2}^n \frac{1}{m^k} = \sum\limits_{m=1}^\infty \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-2} \frac{1}{m^{k+2}} = \sum\limits_{m=1}^\infty \frac{1}{m^2} \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-2} \frac{1}{m^k} = \sum\limits_{m=1}^1 \frac{1}{m^2} \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-2} \frac{1}{m^k} + \sum\limits_{m=2}^\infty \frac{1}{m^2} \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-2} \frac{1}{m^k} =$$

$$= n-1 + \sum\limits_{m=2}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{m^2} \cdot \frac{1 - \frac{1}{m^{n-1}}}{1 - \frac{1}{m}}\right) = n-1 + \sum\limits_{m=2}^\infty \frac{m^{n-1} - 1}{(m - 1)m^n} = n-1 + \sum\limits_{m=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(m+1)m} - \sum\limits_{m=2}^\infty \frac{1}{(m-1)m^n} = n - \sum\limits_{m=1}^\infty \frac{1}{m(m+1)^n}$$

So
$$a^n \left(n - \sum\limits_{k=2}^n \zeta(k)\right) = a^n \sum\limits_{m=2}^\infty \frac{1}{(m-1)m^n} = \sum\limits_{m=2}^\infty \frac{1}{m-1} \left(\frac{a}{m}\right)^n$$

Comment: I didn't solve the entire problem, but maybe this can help 
We have
 $$\lim_{n\to+\infty}a^n(n-\zeta(2)-\zeta(3)-\cdots-\zeta(n))=\lim_{n\to+\infty} a^n \left(\sum_{k=2}^n \left(1-\zeta(k)\right)+1\right)=\lim_{n\to+\infty} a^n (-1+1)=0$$
as $\sum_\limits{n \ge2} (\zeta(n)-1)=1 $ (see e.g [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particular_values_of_the_Riemann_zeta_function#Series_involving_%CE%B6(n))) The last equality should be formally proven, of course

Comment: where did you got this question from is it from a problem book ? if yes then please tell me the name of it , because I think this book would be very intersting

Comment: @pie I'm sorry; I don't know about the source.

Comment: Which *definition* of the digamma function is available to you?

Comment: @metamorphy https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function